# In flutter development, how to print long string in visual studio code debug console?

Tags: visual-studio-code, flutter

I want to print large string in flutter but they are truncated.

Example, this is 1342 characters string:

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do
>   eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad
>   minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut
>   aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in
>   reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla
>   pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in
>   culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum
>   dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor
>   incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
>   quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea
>   commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate
>   velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint
>   occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt
>   mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur
>   adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore
>   magna aliqua. Ut enim ad'); // minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation
>   ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute
>   irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu
>   fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident,
>   sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

Only the top 1022 characters will be printed.

I try to use `debugPrint` and `print` functions but nothing.

What I can do?

Comment: Why not use the debugger?

Comment: I need to print them on the console or redirect the output on text file (if possible).

Answer (score 1):

That's due to VS Code truncating big strings, usually bigger than 1000 char of being printed at once. 
You can try a little "hack" by splitting it into words and print each of it.

`myLongString.split(' ').forEach((word) => print(" " + word));`

You can also try to use the [logging](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/logging) package, but probably it will experience the same problem when trying to print the whole string, since it is trying to stdout all at once.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `log(message)` function.